# ошибка с использованием Event

Tags: javascript, html

`event` зачеркнут и появляется это пояснение:

> Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative less
>   Inspection info: Checks for using deprecated functions and variables.
>   The validation orks in JavaScript, html, or jsp files.

```js
function openCart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/cart/open',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      $('#cart .modal-content').html(res);
      $('#cart').modal('show');
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Неизвестная ошибка');
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openCart(event)">Корзина</a>
```

ошибка в браузере:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openCart is not defined
>   at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM32 :21)

Comment: @meine, как ты себе это представляешь? :-)

Comment: @ohwoow, на какую именно строку идет сообщение _Deprecated symbol used..._?

Comment: и кто именно пишет это сообщение?

Comment: на строку с ссылкой,на команду event. Пишет PhpStorm. Из-за  этого корзина просто не открывается.

Comment: корзина не из-за этого не открывается, а из-за того, что у тебя openCart не глобальная функция

Answer (score 1):

> Из-за этого корзина просто не открывается.

Корзина не открывается из-за ошибки

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openCart is not defined at
>   HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM32 :21)

А эта ошибка возникает, потому что функция `openCart` определена внутри другой функции и, по этой причине, не видна в глобальной области видимости.